# Is tilde accepted in Bash script for macOS? (Trying to get a user's documents folder path.)

Tags: bash, macos, tilde

I'm trying to write a Bash script for macOS to create a directory in a user's documents folder. I do this:

```
dmg_dir="~/Documents/My dir"

# Create a directory
$(mkdir -p "$dmg_dir")
```

But it fails as the interpreter seems not to unfold the tilde in the path.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take the tilde out of the quotes

Comment: And don't use `$( )` unnecessarily.

Comment: Quotes in shell are handled in a character by character basis; one of the many correct ways to write your code would be `dmg_dir=~/Documents/"My dir"`, so the space is inside the quotes but the tilde is not.